# Why the cookie value is not being set after omitting or adding blank white space('') as the 'expire' parameter in setcookie() function?

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies, setcookie, httpcookie

I'm using **PHP 7.2.0**

I want to omit the expire parameter in `setcookie()` function while setting the cookie, so I tried below code and got Parse error in output.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
$cookie_n = "user";
$cookie_value = "John Doe";
setcookie($cookie_n, $cookie_value, , "/"); 
?>
<html>
<body>

<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_n])) {
     echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_n . "' is not set!";
} else {
     echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_n . "' is set!<br>";
     echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_n];
}
?>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> You might have to reload the page to see the value of the cookie.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

**Output :**
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in ... on line 5

Then I tried with below `setcookie()` code but I got Warning and the cookie didn't get set:

```
setcookie($cookie_n, $cookie_value, '' , "/");
```

**Output :**

```
Warning: setcookie() expects parameter 3 to be integer, string given in ... on line 5
Cookie named 'user' is not set!

Note: You might have to reload the page to see the value of the cookie.
```

From manual consider below text about expire parameter,

> If set to 0, or omitted, the cookie will expire at the end of the
>   session (when the browser closes).

So, according to this I tried the code but it's not working and generating parse error and notice. Please someone help me and correct the mistake I'm making in my code.

I also want to know, whether the cookie value set by omitting expire parameter value will be alive after closing the respective browser tab only and not the entire web browser?

Can I set cookies from Command Line? If yes, how? If no, why?

Thank You.

Comment: Omitting means `0` or `NULL`. The manual did not mention empty strings being valid.

Comment: @mario : Thanks. It'w working with NULL. Manual should clearly had to mention this instead of using vague and confusing explanation. Instead of the word omitting they could have used setting NULL. What do you think about this?

Comment: @SerialKisser, the documentation indicates that all the parameters starting with ``$value`` are optional, but more important, if you omit one, you must omit all the rest. If you want to omit one or more parameter, but not a subsequent parameter, you must provide a placeholder value for the parameters you wish to omit. You can learn more about [Extended Backus-Naur Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form)